# How to Generate one time 6 digit password in php?

Tags: php, security, cryptography

How to generate a one time password in PHP for 2 factor authentication using mobiles

Comment: By using an algorithm that generates a one time password. Happy to help. -1 for lack of.. everything.

Comment: Don't see no reason to downvote. The question title posed a legit question. Could have been better/further formulated, but was still easy to understand.

Comment: @Chrules: If you think this is a good question please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) which should convince you otherwise. This is *not* a "write my code for me" site.

Comment: @Clive not a "good" question, presuming the OP has no programming experience, it is not a bad one either.   We could easily have pointed in the direction of: "Use a random generator, or a hash generator." which would make the OP do the search himself. But we just like to answer the best we can :)

Comment: @Chrules: The question shows no research effort whatsoever; it is therefore a bad question, regardless of the OPs programming experience. You can clearly see the community as a whole agrees with this assertion by just looking at the number of downvotes the question has received. People don't downvote and close questions for fun, only when they see something that doesn't belong here. And this question certainly fits the bill :) They may also have looked at OPs other questions which are all very low quality.

Comment: function createRandomPassword() {



    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789";

    srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

    $i = 0;

    $pass = '' ;



    while ($i <= 6) {

        $num = rand() % 33;

        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);

        $pass = $pass . $tmp;

        $i++;

    }



    return $pass;



}



// Usage

$password = createRandomPassword();

echo "Your random password is: $password";
?>

Comment: Don't use `rand()` for this. Use [`random_int()`](https://secure.php.net/random_int).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
function generatePassword($length, $strength) 
{
    $vowels = 'aeuy';
    $consonants = 'bdghjmnpqrstvz';
    if ($strength & 1) 
    {
        $consonants .= 'BDGHJLMNPQRSTVWXZ';
    }
    if ($strength & 2) 
    {
        $vowels .= "AEUY";
    }
    if ($strength & 4) 
    {
        $consonants .= '23456789';
    }
    if ($strength & 8) 
    {
        $consonants .= '@#$%';
    }
    $password = '';
    $alt = time() % 2;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) 
    {
        if ($alt == 1) 
        {
            $password .= $consonants[(rand() % strlen($consonants))];
            $alt = 0;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $password .= $vowels[(rand() % strlen($vowels))];
            $alt = 1;
        }
    }
    return $password;
}


    echo generatePassword(6,4);
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
<?php    
$pass= rand(100000, 999999);
?>
```

Comment: Nice, quick, clean and easy... if you just want numbers ;)

Comment: op says 6 digit password. so, there isn't any reason to think he needs more than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like md5 or sha1 to do this:

```
print substr(md5("text"), 0, 6);
```

If it must be unique, you probably want to either check with a database where you store already generated passwords, or use a longer password since 6 digits can be used pretty quickly.

You say digits, if only numbers, you can do:

```
print mt_rand(100000, 999999);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
/*****
Returns a randomized string of chars/sybols/numbers for specified length
@param $l = length (default=8)
@param $s = use symbols? T/F
@param $a = use alpha characters? T/F
@param $n = use numbers? T/F
*****/
function random_chars($l=8,$s=1,$a=1,$n=1) {
  $string = ''; $chars = array();
  if ($s) $chars = array_merge($chars,array(
                     33,35,36,37,38,40,41,42,43,44,45,
                     46,47,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,91,93,
                     94,95,123,124,125,126
                     ));
  if ($a) $chars = array_merge($chars,array(
                     65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,
                     75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,
                     85,86,87,88,89,90,
                     97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,
                     107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,
                     117,118,119,120,121,122
                     ));
  if ($n) $chars = array_merge($chars,array(
                     48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57
                     ));
  for ($i=0;$i<$l;$i++) {shuffle($chars);$string.=chr(reset($chars));}
  return $string;
  }
?>
```

Example:

```
$password = random_chars(12); // 12-length alpha/numbers/symbols
$password = random_chars(12,0); // 12-length alpha/numbers
$password = random_chars(12,0,0); // 12-length numbers only
```

Comment: This code is ugly, why not to use loops? Is it convenient to type all those numbers?

Comment: I found many characters cause issues, i use this function for a lot more than just one-time-passwords, so i hard-coded which chars to use, you'll notice there's a few chars missing here n there

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

function random($length = 6)
{      
    $chars = 'bcdfghjklmnprstvwxzaeiou0123456789';
    $result = '';

    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++)
    {
        $result .= ($p%2) ? $chars[mt_rand(19, 23)] : $chars[mt_rand(0, 18)];
    }

    return $result;
}
echo random();
?>
```